# Hibernate Generation Type for SQL Server and Others

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, hibernate, auto-increment

I wrote program that uses different databases like sql server, oracle etc.  My problem is that I can't handle GenerationType and insert correct row into table. Using GenerationType.AUTO and hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings := false in sql server, my program is able to insert new row into table, but ID is always null, same problem is when GenerationType is IDENTITY.

I tried to add auto-incrementation only for sql server, but Liquibase yells at me that it's not supported for mssql. When I use Sequences for Oracle as well SQL Server my program is trying to get "next value" from generator but it cannot and do infinite loop. Even if I set default value for ID it won't increment this value.

Thats my code :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "name")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "name", sequenceName = "SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
private Long id;
```

I would like to be able to add auto-incrementing indices into table and it should work for SQL Server databases and I don't want to use Table strategy for generation because it needs additional table in db.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I add condition in Liquibase xml file that checks whether db is mssql type and if it's true script drops ID column and adds it with IDENTITY(1,1) option.

The only problem is that now I have to switch aforementioned "hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" setting.